# How to make a EAP methods to work synchronously

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I am using CefSharp 3 in my WPF application to use Chromium based webBrowser control. In order to invoke some script in html `ExecutScriptAsync`method is used. This is an EAP(Event-based Asynchronous Pattern) and i want to run this function synchronously as running it asynchronously is creating a huge mess in my output. 
As it is EAP I cannot `await` it.
If I await it it throws an error saying `Cannot await void`

Please help..

Comment: You should be able use `TaskFactory.FromAsync` to get a `Task` you can await.

Comment: I think that can be done only for APM(Asynchronous Programming Model)

Comment: Actually it's `Observable.FromEventPattern` in the reactive extensions library. You should be able to use `Observable.FromEventPattern(...).Take(1).ToTask()` to create a `Task` from the first value of an event.

Comment: See [A reusable pattern to convert event into task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783741/a-reusable-pattern-to-convert-event-into-task). Note however if you want to do `task.Wait()`, you may end up with a classic deadlock, unless you host CefSharp on a separate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to do this:

1. Make the event handler signal an event
2. Wait for the event

If you are using await then a `TaskCompletionSource` is a good "event". If you are going synchronous I'd probably still use that and simply `Wait` on the task that would be provided by the TCS.

Comment: Can you help me out with some sample? or just refer me the link of some nice tutorial that I can follow.

Comment: I don't have anything handy. Any concrete problems? Is the idea clear?

Comment: Okay I will try to go with the approach as suggested and get back to you if my issue continue. Thank you. :)