# Awaiting Process.Start with Observable

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, system.reactive

I have created the following code. I supposed it would work, but it doesn't. The await hangs there indefinitely (Exit event is never called).

I'm calling "ping" with no arguments, so it would end almost immediately.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    FileName = "ping", 
                    UseShellExecute = false, 
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true, 
                    RedirectStandardError = true,                    

                },
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            };


            var obs = Observable.FromEventPattern(handler => process.Exited += handler, handler => process.Exited -= handler);

            var started = process.Start();
            if (!started)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not start process: " + process);
            }

            await obs.FirstAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make it work using IObservable?

Answer (score 2):

You have a race condition here. A quote from [this RX repro thread](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/16#issuecomment-53468621):

> FirstAsync returns a cold observable. It’s not until you subscribe to
>   it or await that you’ll receive messages.

Unlike `TaskCompletionSource` (the use of which might be more appropriate here, IMO), the observable returned by `FirstAsync`doesn't "cache" the event that had occurred *before* you activated the subscription by awaiting it. So, `process.Exited` event gets triggered before `await obs.FirstAsync()` and thus the .NET startup code blocks on the task returned by `Main`.

The following would work as expected (you'd need to add `using System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks`):

```
var task = obs.FirstAsync().ToTask();

var started = process.Start();
if (!started)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not start process: " + process);
}

await task;
```

Here we activate the observable subscription by converting it to a `Task`, before starting the process.

If interested in something like `Observable.FromEventPattern` but for `TaskCompletionSource`, check [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783741/a-reusable-pattern-to-convert-event-into-task).