# Create ice cold TaskCompletionSource?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm writing a library which includes scheduling functionality (not the standard `TaskScheduler`, `IScheduler`...) based on .Net Tasks. I'm using `TaskCompletionSource`, and `Task.Status` is critical for representing the status of underlying operations, *including* `TaskStatus.Created`, i.e. created but not yet started. I know returned Tasks should normally be hot, but for my manually controlled proxy Tasks, I really do want them initially as `Created`.

Unfortunately for me, the initial status of `TaskCompletionSource.Task` is `WaitingForActivation`, i.e. it's already gone past `Created`. Put differently, `TaskCompletionSource` supports *two* states, but I need ***three*** states:

**Question**: How can I get a `Task` that I can manually set to ***three*** different states? I.e. `Task.Status` can be set to:

1) `Created`
2) One of `WaitingForActivation`/`WaitingForChildrenToComplete`/`WaitingToRun`/`Running`
3) Either of `RanToCompletion`/`Canceled`/`Faulted`

The code below understandably complains about the type mismatch. I can instead wrap the Task by changing `new Task<TResult>` to `new Task<Task<TResult>>`, but to get back to `Task<TResult>` I have to `Unwrap()` it, and the unwrapped task will have status `WaitingForActivation`, bringing me back to square one.

I will have a large number of these, so blocking a thread with `Wait()` for each is not an option.

I have considered inheriting from `Task` and overriding members (using new), but if possible it would be nice to give the library user an actual `Task` instead of a `DerivedTask`, especially since I present regular Tasks to also be awaited in many other places.

Ideas?

```
private TaskCompletionSource<TResult> tcs;

private async Task<TResult> CreateStartCompleteAsync()
{
    await tcs.Task;
    if (tcs.Task.IsCanceled)
    {
        throw new OperationCanceledException("");
    }
    else if // etc.
}

public ColdTaskCompletionSource()
{
    tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();
    Task = new Task<TResult>(() => CreateStartCompleteAsync());
}
```

Errors:
* Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
* Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'TResult'

Comment: I think I've answered a closely related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22705236/1768303).

Comment: I think if you want to have more control you should not base your API on `Task` but on a custom class that exposes exactly the information you want to expose. You can also expose a `Task` but the status info would come from your own class.

Comment: @Noseratio: The `Task` in your linked code only goes through 2 states: `Created` and "Completed", similar to `TaskCompletionSource.Task` only going through 2 states (`WaitingForActivation` and "Completed"). I need **3** states (`Created`, `Running`, "Completed"), and my example code above attempts to use async-await to accomplish this, but as explained doesn't work due to type mismatch. I don't see how to modify your linked code to support **3** states - any ideas?

Comment: @usr: Yes I could create my own awaitable with custom status info, but I use regular (non-proxy) Tasks in many places, and want to present a single (standard i.e. Task) awaitable type to the library user. On the second suggestion: giving the user both a Task (which has Status) and my own separate status property would also be confusing and undesirable. Do let me know if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: You understood correctly. I do not want to derail the question but why do you *need* to return a Created task? What decisions are being made based on that status? Can't you just use Created || WaitingForActivation?

Comment: Kristian, the task can only have `Running` state when it's actually executing something, i.e., holding a thread (that includes a blocking `Wait`). If the task is awaiting continuation (i.e. pending at the `await` points), its status is `WaitingForActivation`. Are you happy to sacrifice the scalability of your library for the sake of using `Running` instead of `WaitingForActivation`?

Comment: @Noseratio: I will have a large number of these, so blocking a thread with Wait() for each is not an option, and hence my async-await attempt. I don't care if the second state is WaitingForActivation or WaitingToRun or..., just that it's separate from Created and from "Completed" states.

Comment: @usr: For my underlying operations there is logically a big difference between being "Not started" and "Started", and the library uses this status for other decisions. Being able to use `TaskStatus` directly would significantly reduce complexity and potential confusion.

Comment: @KristianWedberg I understand. I think its a misuse of the TPL to overload internal status codes with concepts only present in your scheduling library. I'd create a `class ScheduledTask { MyStatusEnum Status; Task Completed; }`. You can even make this type awaitable although I think that's an anti-pattern. Anyway, your question is valid and should be answered as asked.

Comment: @usr TaskStatus codes are obviously part of the _public_ API, but I take your point, it e.g. wouldn't be inconceivable for new codes to be added. If instead TaskCompletionSource supported Created tasks directly, nobody would think twice about using it. I can feel a pull request coming when all of TPL is open sourced and available :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I agree with @usr's points in the comments, technically you still can have an implementation that provides these states:

1. `Created`
2. `WaitingToRun`
3. Either `RanToCompletion/Canceled/Faulted`

To avoid blocking threads with `Task.Wait`, you could use an internal helper `TaskScheduler`, which would first transition the task from `Created` to `WaitingToRun` and, eventually, to one of the completed states.

The code below illustrates this concept. It was only very slightly tested, might be not fully thread-safe and perhaps could be improved to share a single instance of `FakeTaskScheduler` across multiple tasks.

```
public class ColdTaskCompletionSource
{
    public sealed class FakeTaskScheduler : TaskScheduler
    {
        Task _task;

        public FakeTaskScheduler()
        {
        }

        protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
        {
            _task = task;
        }

        protected sealed override bool TryDequeue(Task task)
        {
            if (task != _task)
                return false;

            _task = null;
            return true;
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
        {
            if (_task == null)
                yield break;
            yield return _task;
        }

        protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel
        {
            get { return 1; }
        }

        public bool Execute()
        {
            if (_task == null)
                return false;

            var task = _task;
            _task = null;
            return base.TryExecuteTask(task);
        }
    }

    readonly Task _task;
    readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    readonly object _lock = new Object();
    readonly FakeTaskScheduler _ts = new FakeTaskScheduler();
    Action _completionAction = null;

    // helpers

    void InvokeCompletionAction()
    {
        if (_completionAction != null)
            _completionAction();
    }

    void Complete()
    {
        if (_task.Status != TaskStatus.WaitingToRun)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid Task state");
        _ts.Execute();
    }

    // public API

    public ColdTaskCompletionSource()
    {
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _task = new Task(InvokeCompletionAction, _cts.Token);
    }

    public Task Task { get { return _task; } }

    public void Start()
    {
        _task.Start(_ts);
    }

    public void SetCompleted()
    {
        lock (_lock)
            Complete();
    }

    public void SetException(Exception ex)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _completionAction = () => { throw ex; };
            Complete();
        }
    }

    public void SetCancelled()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _completionAction = () =>
            {
                _cts.Cancel();
                _cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            };
            Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Noseratio: This worked very well, much appreciated! The above code _requires_ calling Start() as per my 'spec'. I revised it to make calling Start() optional by taking the lock also in Start(): `lock(_lock) _task.Start(_ts);`, and in Complete() instead of throwing I do: `if (_task.Status == TaskStatus.Created) _task.Start(_ts);`

Answer (score 2):

You can't in a reasonable way.

The `Task` status is handled internally and the only API for creating tasks manually is using `TaskCompletionSource`. You also can't inherit from `Task` since the `Status` property is only a getter and you can't reach the backing field `m_stateFlags` since it's internal.

However, the unreasonable way would be to create a task that waits on a `TaskCompletionSource` and you control the task's status be controlling the `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var task = new Task(() => taskCompletionSource.Task.Wait(cancellationTokenSource.Token), cancellationTokenSource.Token); // task.Status == TaskStatus.Created

task.Start(); // task.Status == TaskStatus.Running

taskCompletionSource.SetResult(false) // task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion
```

Or

```
taskCompletionSource.SetException(new Exception("")) // task.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted
```

Or

```
cancellationTokenSource.Cancel() // task.Status == TaskStatus.Cancelled
```

I'm not really recommending you do that. I'm not sure why you want to control `Task`'s status but you probably need to create your own construct you can manage yourself instead of forcing `Task` into a design it wasn't meant for.

Comment: Why create a hot-running `Task` only to block a pool thread with `Task.Wait()`? It's quite [possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22705236) to simulate `TaskCompletionSource` with a cold `Task`. It might not be perfect either as it exposes the inner `Task` to the caller, but IMO still better than blocking.

Comment: @Noseratio *"How can I get a Task that I manually set the Status (Created, **Running**, RanToCompletion, Canceled, Faulted)"*

Comment: @i3arnon: Edited the question - I have many of these and `Wait()` is not an option.