# Timeout exception after async commands and Task.WhenAny awaits in StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, .net, exception, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm experiencing the so-called *Timeout performing HGET company:product:settings, inst: 1, queue: 8, qu=0, qs=8, qc=0, wr=0/0, in=79/1* timeout exception.

It's strange because the same Redis instance and in the same machine is storing data, but it's a specific application which throws this exception. *Update:* In fact, the same application, one line above receives data from Redis. The issue is with `HGET`.

Also, I've increased timeouts on multiplexer configuration to 6 seconds with no luck.

In addition, I've checked that `IDatabase` instance has `IsConnected` with `true` value.

How to interpret these error messages and what's the issue behind the whole timeout?

### Some background...

I've successfully fixed the issue changing *when* some code section gets a *database* (i.e. `multiplexer.GetDatabase()`).

While *multiplexer* has an instance per `AppDomain` as described in StackExchange.Redis documentation, many inversion of control components are creating many instances of `IDatabase` in their own code. That is, `IDatabase` instance isn't shared.

Actual code is performing a `ListRightPopLeftPush`, and after that, it's instantiating an inversion of control component which reads a hash key during component instatiation. If instantiate the whole component before doing the so-called `ListRightPopLeftPush`, then the whole `HashGet` won't throw the timeout exception.

It seems like even when `ListRightPopLeftPush` is executed from other `IDatabase` instance, it produces some kind of issue in the next `IDatabase` instance when it comes to perform read operations.

Anyway, my *fix* doesn't answer the question. I've just added more detailed info to let us find what's the issue and its own solution.

### Update

Anyway, the above "fix" won't fix further read accesses to Redis. I'm getting the same timeout exception in further calls. And now `in` paramater found in exception's message says `60/1`.

Comment: The in=79/1 tells me that there is data available and that a reader is processing it; I will need to check to see if there is any way the reader could be stalled here.

Comment: @MarcGravell Hey, and how you want to check that? Anyway, this is code at work, we should check that next monday...

Comment: @MarcGravell Nevermind, I understand you're going to check in some test ;)

Comment: @MarcGravell Did you get any clue about what's behind the issue? If you need further details you can ask for them and I'll add them to the question

Comment: @MarcGravell I've added new details because I could "fix" the issue changing some execution order in my code. Maybe this gives you more info...

Comment: `IDatabase` doesn't need to be shared; it is a lightweight pass-thru and does nothing more than hold the database number; are you *sure* your IoC is using the same multiplexer for each?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah, I'm not sharing `IDatabase` instances. I'm sure about the multiplexer as a single instance because it's instantiated in a static constructor of some factory which isn't an IoC component.

Comment: not sharing IDatabase instances won't matter at all, unless you are creating so many of them that you're genuinely impacting GC; a static constructor should indeed result in a shared multiplexer; very odd.

Comment: @MarcGravell I've checked that it shares the multiplexer, but this was an expected behavior (because of the static constructor...). No idea of what can be the cause? Ah, I've updated to the latest StackExchange.Redis Nuget package and I'm still experiencing the same issue... argh!

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing indicative code for the two (working vs non-working) scenarios; it is very hard to visualize at the moment

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't know if I said that the same line will work in other scenarios. I mean, the issue arises in a specific use case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60377/discussion-between-matias-fidemraizer-and-marc-gravell).

Comment: @MarcGravell I've edited question's title. I believe that now it tells more about the issue.

Comment: For info: I have an experimental fix - we're dogfooding it currently. It is available on nuget as [1.0.329](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis/1.0.329)

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm going to try it

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah! It worked for me! Thank you for your effort

Comment: let me know how you get on with that

Comment: @MarcGravell yes, if I found any new problem around the same issue I'll give you more info, but it seems that the latest nuget that you published solves the issue (at least in my code)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on a [long discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60377/discussion-between-matias-fidemraizer-and-marc-gravell), and a lot of digging, it looks like in some obscure scenarios the TPL is hijacking the dedicated reader thread when we are doing things like `.TrySetResult` (which: we do often). This causes an instant deadlock if you make a synchronous call, since it can't possibly process any socket data if it is busy waiting for a task to complete (which would only ever be completed by itself). We do actually have [code in place *specifically to prevent this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579206/how-can-i-prevent-synchronous-continuations-on-a-task), but it looks like the workaround actually *forces* it to happen in some other scenarios. Which... is horrible. I will see what I can find. But basically, the problem is that *currently*, in *some limited scenarios*, `TaskCompletionSource.TrySetResult` is giving power to the TPL to run synchronous continuations. This includes `Task.WhenAny`.

Comment: I don't know if I should mark this as *solved* or we can leave it open until you release a new version of StackExchange.Redis library solving the issue. What's your opinion?

Comment: if you want, it would be useful that your answer would explain that starting from X version the issue got solved!

Comment: I've got something like this happening in a Nancy app, and I'm not sure if this is to blame or not. Any updates on *what* the limited Scenarios *are* that can cause this to happen?

Comment: In case it's important this is happening for me in version `1.0.371` framework 4.5, and I'm not able to reproduce it in unit tests, just the Nancy App.

Comment: Does this mean we should or shouldn't be using async methods?