# How to continue TaskCompletionSource<> in another thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-core, taskcompletionsource

I'm using `TaskCompletionSource<>` quite often. I have a network protocol design, where I receive many streams in one tcp/ip connection. I demultiplex those streams and then inform the corresponding "SubConnections" of new content.

Those "SubConnections" (which are waiting via `await`) then should continue in a new thread.

Usually I solve such issues by putting the `TaskComplectionSource<>.Set` call in an anonymous `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` method, like this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { tcs.SetResult(null); });
```

If I don't do this the corresponding `await tcs.Task` call will continue in the thread which called `tcs.SetResult`.

However, I'm aware of that this isn't the right way to do things. It's also possible to self-write a `SynchronizationContext` (or something) which will instruct the `await` call to continue in another thread.

**My primary question here is: How would I do this in the "best practice" way?**

My hope here is also to avoid the `ThreadPool` overhead, because it's quite high on Linux compared to just blocking a thread and waiting for a `ManualResetEvent` - even though the `SynchronizationContext` (or whatever) may also utilize the `ThreadPool`.

*Please refrain from telling me that it's generally a bad idea to multiplex something in one tcp/ip connection or that I should just use System.IO.Pipelines, REST or whatever. **This is my scenario.** Thank you.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the `TaskCompletionSource` using [`TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskCreationOptions_RunContinuationsAsynchronously) (in .NET 4.6+):

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Result>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
...
tcs.SetResult(...);
```

See e.g. [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321457/taskcontinuationoptions-runcontinuationsasynchronously-and-stack-dives) for more details.