# Did I get TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously right? Apparently not... Why?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

Coming from [Task.Run doesn't execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61096543/task-run-doesnt-execute) and after having read  [TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously and Stack Dives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321457/taskcontinuationoptions-runcontinuationsasynchronously-and-stack-dives), I wanted to confirm that I got this right:

When used for a `TaskCompletionSource`:

- If `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` *is* set, then `TaskCompletionSource.SetResult()` will send all continuations to the thread pool where they will be queued and processed, maybe similar to wrapping them all in `Task.Run()` calls. The continuations will be processed asynchronously, on parallel thread pool threads, not blocking the current thread/task.
- If `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` is *not* set (the default, I'm assuming), then all continuations (= delegates in `Task.ContinueWith()` calls) are executed synchronously, one after the other on the thread that called `TaskCompletionSource.SetResult()`, blocking that current thread/task until all continuations have been processed, maybe similar to the way event delegates are processed.

I wrote the following test to try and confirm these assumptions:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestTaskCreationOptions()
    {
        void callback(int i, int sleep)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i} {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Description()} - before sleep {sleep}");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleep);
            Console.WriteLine($"{i} {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Description()} - after sleep {sleep}");
        }

        void test(TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"starting: {tcs.Task.CreationOptions}");
            tcs.Task.ContinueWith((t) => callback(1,1000));
            tcs.Task.ContinueWith((t) => callback(2,300));
            tcs.Task.ContinueWith((t) => callback(3,300));

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                callback(-1,100);
                tcs.SetResult(null);
                callback(-2,100);


            });
            Console.WriteLine("waiting");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("done");
        }

        test(new TaskCompletionSource<object>( TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously));
        test(new TaskCompletionSource<object>());
    }
```

And here are the (annotated) results:

```
    starting: RunContinuationsAsynchronously
    waiting
    -1 [11, Back, Pool] - before sleep 100
    -1 [11, Back, Pool] - after sleep 100

    -2 [11, Back, Pool] - before sleep 100

    1 [12, Back, Pool] - before sleep 1000 --> continuations are correctly executed on different threads
    2 [15, Back, Pool] - before sleep 300
    3 [13, Back, Pool] - before sleep 300

    -2 [11, Back, Pool] - after sleep 100  --> continuations correctly do not block the calling task/thread

    3 [13, Back, Pool] - after sleep 300
    2 [15, Back, Pool] - after sleep 300
    1 [12, Back, Pool] - after sleep 1000

    done

    starting: None

    -1 [13, Back, Pool] - before sleep 100
    waiting
    -1 [13, Back, Pool] - after sleep 100

    -2 [13, Back, Pool] - before sleep 100

    1 [15, Back, Pool] - before sleep 1000 --> continuations are incorrectly(?!) executed on different threads
    2 [14, Back, Pool] - before sleep 300
    3 [16, Back, Pool] - before sleep 300

    -2 [13, Back, Pool] - after sleep 100

    2 [14, Back, Pool] - after sleep 300 --> continuations incorrectly(?!) do not block the calling task/thread
    3 [16, Back, Pool] - after sleep 300
    1 [15, Back, Pool] - after sleep 1000
    done
```

So, apparently, my 2nd assumption (without specifying the flag) was wrong: continuations are not run *synchronously* - at least not as I understand the term; they are executed on separate threads, so they do not block the calling thread or each other.

Why?