# Async version of Monitor.Pulse/Wait

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm trying to optimize an async version of something similar (in basic funcionality) to the Monitor.Wait and Monitor.Pulse methods. The idea is to use this over an async method.

Requirements:
1) I have one Task running, that it is in charge of waiting until someone pulses my monitor.
2) That task may compute a complex (ie: time consuming) operation. In the meanwhile, the pulse method could be called several times without doing anything (as the main task is already doing some processing).
3) Once the main task finishes, it starts to Wait again until another Pulse comes in.

Worst case scenario is Wait>Pulse>Wait>Pulse>Wait..., but usually I have tenths/hundreds of pulses for every wait.

So, I have the following class (working, but I think it can be optimized a bit based on my requirements)

```
internal sealed class Awaiter
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<TaskCompletionSource<byte>> _waiting = new ConcurrentQueue<TaskCompletionSource<byte>>();

    public void Pulse()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<byte> tcs;
        if (_waiting.TryDequeue(out tcs))
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(1);
        }
    }

    public Task Wait()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<byte> tcs;
        if (_waiting.TryPeek(out tcs))
        {
            return tcs.Task;
        }

        tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<byte>();
        _waiting.Enqueue(tcs);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

The problem with the above class is the baggage I'm using just for synchronization. Since I will be waiting from one and only one thread, there is really no need to have a ConcurrentQueue, as I always have only one item in it.

So, I simplified it a bit and wrote the following:

```
internal sealed class Awaiter2
{
    private readonly object _mutex = new object();
    private TaskCompletionSource<byte> _waiting;

    public void Pulse()
    {
        var w = _waiting;
        if (w == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        lock (_mutex)
        {
            w = _waiting;
            if (w == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            _waiting = null;
            w.TrySetResult(1);
        }
    }

    public Task Wait()
    {
        var w = _waiting;
        if (w != null)
        {
            return w.Task;
        }

        lock (_mutex)
        {
            w = _waiting;
            if (w != null)
            {
                return w.Task;
            }

            w = _waiting = new TaskCompletionSource<byte>();
            return w.Task;
        }
    }
}
```

That new version is also working ok, but I'm still thinking it can be optimized a bit more, by removing the locks.

I'm looking for suggestions on how I can optimize the second version. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you profiled your code, how much time is it actually spending waiting for the lock? Don't guess where your performance problems are, when doing micro-optimisations like writing lock-free code you really need to profile to see if it is really worth doing it.

Comment: It's not a problem of the lock per se, but this code will be packed in a library that other developers will use at wild and I'm trying to create the most optimized version for this use case. I'm also trying to minimize object allocations, etc.

Comment: @CheloXL: Synchronization primitives are hard to get right. I have a library that [includes an `AsyncMonitor`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.AsyncEx/3.0.1/net45/doc/Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncMonitor) complete with exhaustive unit tests, if that would help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you only have one task ever waiting your function can be simplified to

```
internal sealed class Awaiter3
{
    private volatile TaskCompletionSource<byte> _waiting;

    public void Pulse()
    {
        var w = _waiting;
        if (w == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        _waiting = null;
#if NET_46_OR_GREATER
        w.TrySetResult(1);
#else
        Task.Run(() => w.TrySetResult(1));
#endif

    }

    //This method is not thread safe and can only be called by one thread at a time.
    // To make it thread safe put a lock around the null check and the assignment,
    // you do not need to have a lock on Pulse, "volatile" takes care of that side.
    public Task Wait()
    {
        if(_waiting != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Only one waiter is allowed to exist at a time!");

#if NET_46_OR_GREATER
        _waiting = new TaskCompletionSource<byte>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
#else
        _waiting = new TaskCompletionSource<byte>();
#endif
        return _waiting.Task;
    }
}
```

One behavior I did change. If you are using .NET 4.6 or newer use the code in the `#if NET_46_OR_GREATER` blocks, if under use the else blocks. When you call `TrySetResult` you could have the continuation synchronously run, this can cause `Pulse()` to take a long time to complete. By using `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` in .NET 4.6 or wrapping the `TrySetResult` in a `Task.Run` for pre 4.6 will make sure that `Puse()` is not blocked by the continuation of the task.

See the SO question [Detect target framework version at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436526/detect-target-framework-version-at-compile-time) on how to make a `NET_46_OR_GREATER` definition that works in your code.

Comment: I assume that by .NET 6.0 you mean .NET 4.6?

Comment: Yes, sorry, typo, ill fix

Comment: About the continuation: That means that it is possible for the Task "waiting" to run on the same thread that fired the setresult? (so, the Pulse method will not exit until the Task waiting enters the waiting state again??)...

Comment: @CheloXL yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579206/how-can-i-prevent-synchronous-continuations-on-a-task for more in-depth information.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need the `Wait()` call to return a `Task` but are content with being able to `await Wait()` then you can implement a custom awaiter/awaitable.

See [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx) for an overview of the await pattern used by the compiler.

When implementing custom awaitables you will just be dealing with delegates and the actual "waiting" is left up to you. When you want to "await" for a condition it is often possible to keep a list of pending continuations and whenever the condition comes true you can invoke those continuations. You just need to deal with the synchronization coming from the fact that `await` can be called from arbitrary threads. If you know that you'll only ever `await` from one thread (say the UI thread) then you don't need any synchronization at all!

I'll try to give you a lock-free implementation but no guarantees that it is correct. **If you don't understand why all race conditions are safe you should not use it and implement the async/await protocol using lock-statements or other techniques which you know how to debug.**

```
public sealed class AsyncMonitor
{
    private PulseAwaitable _currentWaiter;

    public AsyncMonitor()
    {
        _currentWaiter = new PulseAwaitable();
    }

    public void Pulse()
    {
        // Optimize for the case when calling Pulse() when nobody is waiting.
        //
        // This has an inherent race condition when calling Pulse() and Wait()
        // at the same time. The question this was written for did not specify
        // how to resolve this, so it is a valid answer to tolerate either
        // result and just allow the race condition.
        //
        if (_currentWaiter.HasWaitingContinuations)
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref _currentWaiter, new PulseAwaitable()).Complete();
    }

    public PulseAwaitable Wait()
    {
        return _currentWaiter;
    }
}

// This class maintains a list of waiting continuations to be executed when
// the owning AsyncMonitor is pulsed.
public sealed class PulseAwaitable : INotifyCompletion
{
    // List of pending 'await' delegates.
    private Action _pendingContinuations;

    // Flag whether we have been pulsed. This is the primary variable
    // around which we build the lock free synchronization.
    private int _pulsed;

    // AsyncMonitor creates instances as required.
    internal PulseAwaitable()
    {
    }

    // This check has a race condition which is tolerated.
    // It is used to optimize for cases when the PulseAwaitable has no waiters.
    internal bool HasWaitingContinuations
    {
        get { return Volatile.Read(ref _pendingContinuations) != null; }
    }

    // Called by the AsyncMonitor when it is pulsed.
    internal void Complete()
    {
        // Set pulsed flag first because that is the variable around which
        // we build the lock free protocol. Everything else this method does
        // is free to have race conditions.
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _pulsed, 1);

        // Execute pending continuations. This is free to race with calls
        // of OnCompleted seeing the pulsed flag first.
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _pendingContinuations, null)?.Invoke();
    }

    #region Awaitable

    // There is no need to separate the awaiter from the awaitable
    // so we use one class to implement both parts of the protocol.
    public PulseAwaitable GetAwaiter()
    {
        return this;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Awaiter

    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        // The return value of this property does not need to be up to date so we could omit the 'Volatile.Read' if we wanted to.
        // What is not allowed is returning "true" even if we are not completed, but this cannot happen since we never transist back to incompleted.
        get { return Volatile.Read(ref _pulsed) == 1; }
    }

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    {
        // Protected against manual invocations. The compiler-generated code never passes null so you can remove this check in release builds if you want to.
        if (continuation == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(continuation));

        // Standard pattern of maintaining a lock free immutable variable: read-modify-write cycle.
        // See for example here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140516-00/?p=973
        // Again the 'Volatile.Read' is not really needed since outdated values will be detected at the first iteration.
        var oldContinuations = Volatile.Read(ref _pendingContinuations);
        for (;;)
        {
            var newContinuations = (oldContinuations + continuation);
            var actualContinuations = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _pendingContinuations, newContinuations, oldContinuations);
            if (actualContinuations == oldContinuations)
                break;

            oldContinuations = actualContinuations;
        }

        // Now comes the interesting part where the actual lock free synchronization happens.
        // If we are completed then somebody needs to clean up remaining continuations.
        // This happens last so the first part of the method can race with pulsing us.
        if (IsCompleted)
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref _pendingContinuations, null)?.Invoke();
    }

    public void GetResult()
    {
        // This is just to check against manual calls. The compiler will never call this when IsCompleted is false.
        // (Assuming your OnCompleted implementation is bug-free and you don't execute continuations before IsCompleted becomes true.)
        if (!IsCompleted)
            throw new NotSupportedException("Synchronous waits are not supported. Use 'await' or OnCompleted to wait asynchronously");
    }

    #endregion
}
```

You usually don't bother on which thread the continuations run because if they are async methods the compiler has already inserted code (in the continuation) to switch back to the right thread, no need to do it manually in every awaitable implementation.

**[edit]**

As a starting point for how a locking implementation can look I'll provide one using a lock-statement. It should be easy to replace it by a spinlock or some other locking technique. By using a struct as the awaitable it even has the advantage that **it does no additional allocation** except for the initial object. (There are of course allocations in the async/await framework in the compiler magic on the calling side, but you can't get rid of these.)

Note that the iteration counter will increment only for every Wait+Pulse pair and will eventually overflow into negative, but that is ok. We just need to bridge the time from the continuation beeing invoked until it can call GetResult. 4 billion Wait+Pulse pairs should be plenty of time for any pending continuations to call its GetResult method. If you don't want that risk you could use a long or Guid for a more unique iteration counter, but IMHO an int is good for almost all scenarios.

```
public sealed class AsyncMonitor
{
    public struct Awaitable : INotifyCompletion
    {
        // We use a struct to avoid allocations. Note that this means the compiler will copy
        // the struct around in the calling code when doing 'await', so for your own debugging
        // sanity make all variables readonly.
        private readonly AsyncMonitor _monitor;
        private readonly int _iteration;

        public Awaitable(AsyncMonitor monitor)
        {
            lock (monitor)
            {
                _monitor = monitor;
                _iteration = monitor._iteration;
            }
        }

        public Awaitable GetAwaiter()
        {
            return this;
        }

        public bool IsCompleted
        {
            get
            {
                // We use the iteration counter as an indicator when we should be complete.
                lock (_monitor)
                {
                    return _monitor._iteration != _iteration;
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            // The compiler never passes null, but someone may call it manually.
            if (continuation == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(continuation));

            lock (_monitor)
            {
                // Not calling IsCompleted since we already have a lock.
                if (_monitor._iteration == _iteration)
                {
                    _monitor._waiting += continuation;

                    // null the continuation to indicate the following code
                    // that we completed and don't want it executed.
                    continuation = null;
                }
            }

            // If we were already completed then we didn't null the continuation.
            // (We should invoke the continuation outside of the lock because it
            // may want to Wait/Pulse again and we want to avoid reentrancy issues.)
            continuation?.Invoke();
        }

        public void GetResult()
        {
            lock (_monitor)
            {
                // Not calling IsCompleted since we already have a lock.
                if (_monitor._iteration == _iteration)
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Synchronous wait is not supported. Use await or OnCompleted.");
            }
        }
    }

    private Action _waiting;
    private int _iteration;

    public AsyncMonitor()
    {
    }

    public void Pulse(bool executeAsync)
    {
        Action execute = null;

        lock (this)
        {
            // If nobody is waiting we don't need to increment the iteration counter.
            if (_waiting != null)
            {
                _iteration++;
                execute = _waiting;
                _waiting = null;
            }
        }

        // Important: execute the callbacks outside the lock because they might Pulse or Wait again.
        if (execute != null)
        {
            // If the caller doesn't want inlined execution (maybe he holds a lock)
            // then execute it on the thread pool.
            if (executeAsync)
                Task.Run(execute);
            else
                execute();
        }
    }

    public Awaitable Wait()
    {
        return new Awaitable(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice!, Yes, I actually don't need a task, as I always await the Wait. Maybe I could use a spinlock in pulse, like `while(Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _waiting, null, w) != w) { }` and an Interlocked.Exchange in Wait?

Comment: @CheloXL - yes you can use spinlocks, but if you are doing explicit locking you can optimize away the allocations for each Wait/Pulse pair by using a struct (not possible when being lock-free). I've added an example using lock-statements, it's easily switched to spinlocks.

Comment: @CheloXL Also, as a syntax gimmic, if you want to be able to write `await monitor` instead of `await monitor.Wait()` you can rename the Wait method to GetAwaiter (and remove the GetAwaiter from the awaitable).

Comment: In the OnCompleted, you nullify `continuation` inside the lock, and then executes `continuation()`... that would lead to a NRE. It's that a copy/paste error? Instead of setting continuation to null.. Can you simply do a `return`?

Comment: @CheloXL yes I did use a return in an earlier version and meant to change the call to `continuation?.Invoke()` because the return was easier to overlook when reading the code - so yes, this is an error while modifying the code, will fix

Comment: @CheloXL For the record, the important things for OnCompleted implementations is (1) invoke the continuation when already completed, otherwise save it for later invocation (2) it's good practice to not hold a lock when invoking the continuations because you don't know what they do, they may wait on someone else who is waiting on your lock (=deadlock)

Comment: sure. Does this also suffers the thread hijacking? So, do I need to run the `execute?.Invoke()` inside a Task.Run? (maybe first check for null and if not, launch the Task.Run).

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in the answer, you are executing the delegates on the thread where you call them (and they switch to a different thread if they need to, but they don't have to switch).

In my opinion it's the callers responsibility to be sensible about this, but if you feel it's better for your application to move this into the awaitable and run continuations on the threadpool (via Task.Run) then thats fine. Thats the advantage of implementing an awaiter yourself, you can decide about the details and the tradeoffs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100697/discussion-between-zarat-and-cheloxl).

Answer (score 2):

Here is my simple async implementation that I use in my projects:

```
internal sealed class Pulsar
{
    private static TaskCompletionSource<bool> Init() => new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _tcs = Init();

    public void Pulse()
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _tcs, Init()).SetResult(true);
    }

    public Task AwaitPulse(CancellationToken token)
    {
        return token.CanBeCanceled ? _tcs.Task.WithCancellation(token) : _tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Add `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` to the TCS for async continuations.

The [`WithCancellation`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading/) can be omitted of course, if you do not need cancellations.

Comment: Note that the tasks awaiting `AwaitPulse` will be executed on the same thread synchronously as part of the `CancellationToken` registration, so the thread running `Pulse()` will block.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to use [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) which uses Monitor.

```
public class AsyncMonitor
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim signal = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);

    public void Pulse()
    {
        try
        {
            signal.Release();
        }
        catch (SemaphoreFullException) { }
    }

    public async Task WaitAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await signal.WaitAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```