# When exactly are synchronous continuations dangerous?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-core, async-await

In a [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/the-danger-of-taskcompletionsourcet-class/), Microsoft's Sergey Tepliakov says:

> you should always provide
> TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously when creating
> TaskCompletionSource instances.

But in that article, unless I misunderstood it, <strike>he also says that all `await` continuations basically act the same way as a `TaskCompletionSource` without `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously`. So this would mean that `async` and `await` are also inherently dangerous and shouldn't be used, unless `await Task.Yield()` is used as well.</strike>

(edit: I did misunderstand it. He's saying that `await` continuing synchronously is the *cause* of the problematic `SetResult` behaviour. `await Task.Yield()` is recommended as a client-side workaround if the task creation can't be controlled at the source. Unless I misunderstood something again.)

I conclude that there must be specific circumstances that make synchronous continuations dangerous, and apparently that those circumstances are common for `TaskCompletionSource` use cases. What are those dangerous circumstances?

Comment: Probably, because it may block the thread. Btw, you can raise your question in original post comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thread theft, basically.

A good example here would be a client library that talks over the network to some server that is implemented as a sequence of frames on the same connection (http/2, for example, or RESP). For whatever reason, imagine that each call to the library returns a `Task<T>` (for some `<T>`) that has been provided by a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` that is awaiting results from the network server.

Now you want to write the read-loop that is dequeing responses from the server (presumably from a socket, stream, or pipeline API), resolve the corresponding `TaskCompletionSource<T>` (which could mean "the next in the queue", or could mean "use a unique correlation key/token that is present in the response").

So you effectively have:

```cs
while (communicationIsAlive)
{
    var result = await ParseNextResultAsync(); // next message from the server
    TaskCompletionSource<Foo> tcs = TryResolveCorrespondingPendingRequest(result);
    tcs?.TrySetResult(result); // or possibly TrySetException, etc
}
```

Now; imagine that you didn't use `RunContinuationsAsynchronously` when you created the `TaskCompletionSource<T>`. The moment you do `TrySetResult`, the continuation executes *on the current thread*. This means that the `await` in some arbitrary client code (which can do *anything*) has now interrupted your IO read loop, and *no other results will be processed* until that thread relinquishes the thread.

Using `RunContinuationsAsynchronously` allows you to use `TrySetResult` (et al) without worrying about your thread being stolen.

(even worse: if you combine this with a subsequent sync-over-async call to the same resource, you can cause a hard deadlock)

Related question from *before* this flag existed: [How can I prevent synchronous continuations on a Task?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22579206/23354).

Comment: So in conclusion: don't complete tasks without RunContinuationsAsynchronously if your code shouldn't be interrupted (SetResult side of the equation), and don't block in task continuations (await side of the equation)?

Comment: Assuming that you don't mind if your loop gets interrupted, sounds like the only reason to set RunContinuationsAsynchronously on a TaskCompletionSource is to guard against someone continuing your task and then blocking indefinitely. But this is a dangerous practice in asynchronous programming and should never be done anyway. So isn't the advice to "always provide TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously" a bit too aggressive?

Comment: @relatively_random "in conclusion" - effectively, yes; but: it isn't necessarily "indefinitely"; even "for a bit" could be hugely harmful to performance if the read loop is the limiting factor. Re "too aggressive" - well, everything is subjective, but how about we soften it to "use `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` unless you can explain exactly what it does and why exactly you actively don't want it in your case" :) suggesting it as the default is the safer option, and will almost always lead to the success scenario